# rspec expect(page).to have_content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rspec-rails

```
require 'rails_helper.rb'

feature 'Creating posts' do  
  scenario 'can create a post' do
    visit '/'
    click_link 'New Post'
    attach_file('Image', "spec/files/images/coffee.jpg")
    fill_in 'Caption', with: 'nom nom nom #coffeetime' 
    click_button 'Create Post'
    expect(page).to have_content('#coffeetime')
    expect(page).to have_css("img[src*='coffee.jpg']")
  end
end
```

So I am trying to run this rspec test and I keep getting the error

Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content('#coffeetime')
       expected to find text "#coffeetime" in "Photogram New Po
st"
     # ./spec/features/creating_posts_spec.rb:10:in `block (2 l
evels) in '

I have checked everything I can think of.  I am following a tutorial and have triple checked everything. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Below is the controller for Post.

```
def create
  @post = Post.create(post_params)
redirect_to @post
end

def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end


private

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:caption, :image) 
end

end
```

Here is the log info:

```
Started POST "/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-04-09 19:56:48 -0700
Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "post"=>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x0055c20c7dc7a0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20170409-14588-93g7fy.jpg>, @original_filename="coffee.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"post[image]\"; filename=\"coffee.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\nContent-Length: 186616\r\n">, "caption"=>"nom nom nom #coffeetime"}, "commit"=>"Create Post"}
Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/24eb05d18318ac2db8b2b959315d10f220170409-14588-ra9l7x.jpg'
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mSAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/24eb05d18318ac2db8b2b959315d10f220170409-14588-ok0ki4.jpg'
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[31mROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[35mSAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/24eb05d18318ac2db8b2b959315d10f220170409-14588-1pbpoah.jpg'
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[31mROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
  Rendering posts/new.html.haml within layouts/application
  Rendered posts/new.html.haml within layouts/application (2.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 15ms (Views: 5.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[31mrollback transaction[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[36mbegin transaction[0m
```

Comment: What does your test.log show?

Comment: Is there a easy way to output the test.log?

Comment: It should be in the log directory in your app root

Comment: That seems to be the relevant data and it looks like it is writing correctly as far as I can tell.

Comment: edit your question, and add the log info there including the rendering and controller steps that occur as a result of the POST

Comment: I found the problem.  I am not sure why it was affected but the issue was a typo for a line that was validating an image in the post.rb file.  I would not have thought to look there since it wasn't relevant to the caption.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: If a file in the post is failing validation then the post fails validation, which means your redirect to the post probably redirects back to creating a new post.  Glad you found the issue.